# Modeling How to solidify or scale an irregular shape, maybe flip vertices?

Tags: modeling, vertices, scale

[image]

I'm trying to make an irregular shaped wall and the inside will be a flower bed.  I started with tracing shape as bezier then convert to mesh but it all got messy.

this time i started with plane, deleted all but one vertex then extruded and used proportional editing to get the shape.

however, i now need to solidify the shape so it's one brick thick and then i will extrude in z axis.

Solidify just went weird and twisted, i managed to flip the normals in z direction but that didn't help solidify as it was in the wrong orientation.

I tried to duplicate and scale hoping that all vertices would move out the same amount...but that didn't work. i'm thinking that it must be to do with normals, which you can see her point in weird directions (and also slightly elevated in z-direction)

ANy help would be great. Thanks

UPDATE: Gorgious method worked for the solidifying. thanks.

however, i'm still intrigued as to how you could have scaled the original shape to make a "larger" version of it. whenever i scaled it, it would scale disproportionately and in weird directions

Comment: Solidify needs a face to work correctly. I think what you want is to extrude along Z axis, THEN solifidy your object

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks.....

Comment: There is Offest Edges addon which [is part of Edit Mesh Tools](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/edit_mesh_tools.html) as of 2.8+. It can extrude or offset complex profiles proportionally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solifidy modifier CAN work with only edge data, but as you realized, there are two caveats :

- The created geometry is edges only, and no new face is created (so the intended behaviour is not respected)
- The created geometry is displaced along the vertices normals, which can be a bit tricky to estimate or to modify in such meshes.

Keeping in mind your desired output, I would do it in this order :

1. Use a Screw modifier in the Z axis. This will create vertical faces, and the normals will face either inward or outward.

[image]

2. Use a Displace modifier. Using default settings, the geometry will get displaced along the normals of your faces, allowing you to effectively "offset" the edges if you look at your mesh from top view. There are limits though, as the geometry can crash into itself if you go too far.

[image]

Consider manual tweaking or reducing the number of vertices. (Might need to add a subdivision surface modifier in that case to smooth out the shape)

[image]

Or / And a Smooth modifier :

[image]

Finally, add the Solidify modifier. You can tweak the offset too.

[image]

Go into the mesh properties and enable "Auto smooth" into the normals panel.

[image]

You can non-destructively tweak the settings :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have converted it to a mesh, and then extruded the points in edit mode.

Another way you could try is to keep it as a bezier curve and remain in object mode and go to

object data properties>geometry>extrude

You can set the bevel and offset at that point, and then convert it to mesh afterwards.

This seems to result in very smooth geometry.